# How to make a StackPanel reorder when using a Search Bar (TextBox) in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, search, stackpanel

CONTEXT:
I have a StackPanel with Buttons inside. These buttons are created, named and put inside the stackPanel programmatically. Then I have a TextBox serving as a Search bar with a button that is utilised as search button.

WHAT I WANT TO DO:
I want that, when the TextBox is filled with the Text of certain Button's Label and the Search Button is clicked, the StackPanel removes the buttons that do not seem to match with the TextBox content and then, when I erase the TextBox's content, reappear (I don't mind if it's in the same order than before or not).

PROBLEM:
I have two main problems, both related to the same: when the Search Button is clicked, it succeeds nothing. Invoking a Button by FindName method doesn't seem to work (it gives me a null . So, my question is: Is it possible to make the StackPanel reorder as I put before? In that case, how would I do that calling the Button created programmatically?

CODE:

```
private void buscarEntrada_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Search button's click event
    //All the buttons are named "Btn" + a constantly increasing number (0,1,2,3...)
    //stackBotones is my StackPanel, I remove the buttons and then readd them depending on the textbox's content
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < stackBotones.Children.Count; i++)
        {
            stackBotones.Children.Remove((UIElement)stackBotones.FindName());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(error);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for reading this.

Comment: You should be using an ItemsControl with the Button in its ItemTemplate. Bind it to a (sorted) collection of data items. Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview).

Comment: Create a list to hold your buttons, and fill it with your programmatically generated buttons, then bind your control to this list and apply a LINQ query to your buttons whenever you supply search text and perform your search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a child element by its name in the `Children` collection like this:

```
string name = txt.Text;
Button button = stackBotones.Children.OfType<Button>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);
```

If you want to remove all elements but the matching one, you could do this in a loop:

```
string name = "b";
for(int i = stackBotones.Children.Count - 1; i>=0; i--)
{
    if (stackBotones.Children[i] is FrameworkElement fe && fe.Name != name)
        stackBotones.Children.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

You may add `stackBotones.Children[i]` to a list that you then use to repopulate `stackBotones.Children` based on your logic.

Comment: Sorry to comment so late, but I was trying to do as you posted. It worked! However, I please request if you can show me a method to ignore the cases while searching. I searched across the Internet but couldn't make it correctly.

Comment: @Clasher: Replace `fe.Name != name` with `!fe.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`